# How i can set an image to another fixed position by touch option?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to build an iPhone app by using Cocos2d. And i would like to set an image to another fixed position from a fixed position by using touch as my wish(speedy, or slowly). I have got some code but it does not work properly.

so friends it will more helpful to me if i get any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little fuzzy, but if you want to set the position of a CocosNode you do:

```
[myNode setPosition:cpv(x,y)];
```

If you want the node to be offset from a touch location, you can do this by implementing ccTouchesBegan:withEvent

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
  CGPoint convertedLocation = [[Director sharedDirector] convertCoordinate:location];

  [myNode setPosition: cpv(convertedLocation.x - 100, convertedLocation.y - 100)];
  return kEventHandled;
}
```

That will offset the CocosNode by -100,-100 to where the touch occurred.

The ccTouchesBegan:withEvent: should be implemented in your Layer, and isTouchesEnabled should be set to YES to enable touches.